# power bi whole column in dax function

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

Is power bi has a functional to input whole column in function instead of one cell from column?[example with single cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKRmi.png) and I got this result [result of calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAcwD.png). But is it possible to input whole column in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You can pass in a list and return a table

Example:

```
let Source = (ColumnData as list) => let
    #"returnTable" = Table.FromList(ColumnData )
    in #"returnTable"
in Source
```

This you can make as your own customer function and call it from other scripts

Be careful to not create a circ. reference.

The way to solve this:

```
MyList = #"Your Table"[TYPE],
    
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Convert", each Convert(MyList))
```

Comment: When I copy your answer, past it and try to add new column using invoke function with one of my column I got this  error https://imgur.com/a/40OuKld      https://imgur.com/a/OWFBpnh   (way I do this https://imgur.com/a/pQM7Sum)

Comment: Most likely what you did was take a column from the same table, this is creating a circular  reference. See enhanced anwser

Comment: Where Should I put your second answer? In new function or what? Sorry I am completely new in Power BI

Comment: In the advanced editor, you can edit the script of your query (select the query, right click, advanced editor). As you had already invoked the function, add the line above to your script (change #"Your table" to the last variable above it) and change the AddColumn to use the list..